# Curly bracket - change height without changing weight using CSS only?

Tags: css, fonts

Is it possible to use only CSS to control a curly bracket's height without affecting it's weight/thickness? I'm trying to dynamically adjust the height of a curly bracket using *font-size*, but that would proportionally increase the weight as well. Is there any way to get around that? Maybe a special kind of font that has a static weight?

Comment: Use an SVG with a non scaling stroke.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use vertical scaling in your text element:

`tranform: scaleY(2)`

Add this to your element and change the scale value as per the requirement.

Comment: This expands things vertically so in the case of the integral sign the circular bits top and bottom become distorted and are no longer circular.